# lsass.exe high I/O with SQL Server 2005 sp3

Tags: sql-server-2005, io

I have a SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition on a Windows Server 2003 Enterprise sp2.
Lately, I get very high I/O(Reda, Write, Other in Task Manager) from process lsass.exe. When I run sysinternals' process monitor on lsass.exe, I get a lot of activity related to SQL Server process. It seems it repeats a pattern of IRP_MJ_CREATE, IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL, IRP_MJ_CLEANUP and IRP_MJ_CLOSE by requests from sql server.
Any suggestions on the cause?

Comment: Belongs on SuperUser.com

Comment: No it doesn't - but it could do with some more data relating to to the level of IO, the spec and config of the server and what it is being used for.

Answer (score 1):

LSASS is the [Local Security Authority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378326%28VS.85%29.aspx) process. LSASS does any work only as a result of security related activity occurring on other processes. A high amount of lsass.exe activity would indicate perhaps a high number of authentication (Kerberos, NTLM) events occurring.

Forget about Task Monitor or Process Monitor. Fire up Perfmon and look at the performance counters if you want to troubleshoot a problem. Get all counters/all instances for the Process category to identify which process consumes CPU/Memory/IO. I would be quite surprised to hear that lsass is truly a performance bottleneck.

I'd recommend you follow the [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) troubleshooting methodology to understand why you experience problems at peak hours. It's a proven methodology with an stellar track record on identifying problem root cause.

Answer (score 0):

The server is a database server. we have about 150 clients that use this server as db server for their application(hospital automation). In task manager, for sqlserver.exe, reads and writes are about 1 million, where lsass is 19,000,000 and it increases between 50-100 every second. This causes a significant decrease in server performance in peak hours.